# Exclude certain HTML tags from eslint checking

Tags: vue.js, webpack, eslint

I'm using a custom Webpack plugin and loader to substitute special markers in a HTML template into valid HTML (similar to a macro in C). This works all fine, the produced HTML turns out fine, but unfortunately, it triggers `eslint` which runs after this substitution (as it would otherwise stumble over these macro markers).
I am fairly flexible with the macro substitution itself, so was thinking about excluding certain warnings from eslint for the substituted markup, however none of the ways to disable eslint work satisfactory.

For instance, if I try to insert `/* eslint-disable-next-line */`in the line `/* eslint-disable-next-line */<my-custom-tag>...` it still raises an error (for instance for `max-len`). I can't use `<!-- eslint-disable -->` as it doesn't seem to work well with Vuejs and `v-if` statements (can't find `v-else`). Inserting a tag before or after the substituted line doesn't work either as that would shift the line numbering for error/warning reporting for eslint.

I was wondering if eslint can be made to ignore certain HTML tags such as `<my-custom-tag>` and within those all the things that one would usually enforce by a linter would be ignored (like generated code which one wouldn't necessarily lint either).

Any suggestions are welcome, in particular if someone can share some experience in modifying eslint (custom rule?) this way?